# Get Values From Repeating Control in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

***How to Get Values From Repeating Control in angular 6***

***I trying to read the Value of this form field at TS file please help how can I do that***

this is repeating block where you can click add and it will create one more control group of that

```
<div *ngIf="subTask.value==5 && subTask.value!=null" formArrayName="itemRows">
        <div *ngFor="let itemrow of taskfrm.controls.itemRows.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <!-- Border START -->
          <div class="add-new-task-border">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <mat-select placeholder="Logical Oprater">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let relationaOpt of relationalOpraters">
                  <mat-option *ngIf="relationaOpt.operatorsType==='logical'" [value]="relationaOpt.id">
                    {{relationaOpt.operator}}
                  </mat-option>
                </ng-container>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="two-way-banding">
              <mat-select placeholder="DataElement 1">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let dataElement of dataElementList" [value]="dataElement.dataElementID">
                  {{dataElement.dataElementName}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="two-way-banding eta-margin-two-way">
              <mat-select placeholder="Relational Oprater">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let relationaOpt of relationalOpraters">
                  <mat-option *ngIf="relationaOpt.operatorsType==='relational'" [value]="relationaOpt.id">
                    {{relationaOpt.operator}}
                  </mat-option>
                </ng-container>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="two-way-banding">
              <mat-select placeholder="DataElement 2">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let dataElement of dataElementList" [value]="dataElement.dataElementID">
                  {{dataElement.dataElementName}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <!-- Border END -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <button *ngIf="subTask.value==5 && subTask.value!=null" style="float:right;" type="button" mat-icon-button color="primary"
        (click)="addNewRow()">
        <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button *ngIf="subTask.value==5 && subTask.value!=null" style="float:right;" type="button" mat-icon-button color="primary"
        (click)="addNewRow()">
        <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
      </button>
```

if you any idea about this, please tell me

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain index in form array:

```
form.controls.itemRows.controls[i].controls.name.value
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="subTask.value==5 && subTask.value!=null" formArrayName="itemRows">
<div *ngFor="let itemrow of taskfrm.controls.itemRows.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">

    <mat-form-field class="col-md-4">
        <input matInput maxlength="20" 
          formControlName="name">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: but How to initialize the formcontrolName in Oninit

Comment: check basic demo in answer

Comment: is it helpful or i create demo??

Comment: i got my solution brother thnks if i need more i ask you